# How can I combine an extra variable to an array/method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I have created a simple program which outputs student details. Ideally I would like to give the user an option to add both courses.  Will this require a lot of messing about changing code? If not can someone help?

```
class Student
{
    public static void main(String[]args)//The main method; starting point of the program.
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String surName, foreName, courseName;
        int age,telephone;

        System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");    
        System.out.println("\t\t\tWelcome to the Mobile College's Student Records");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
        System.out.println("\nHow many students would you like to add?");
        int noStudents = input.nextInt();

        Stu [] TheStu = new Stu [noStudents];

        for (int x = 0; x < noStudents; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter Surname: ");
            surName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Forename: ");
            foreName = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Age: ");
            age = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter Telephone No. ");
            telephone = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Which course do you want to add the student to? .......Literacy or Numeracy  ");
            courseName = input.next();

            TheStu [x] = new Stu (surName, foreName, age, telephone, courseName);
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < noStudents; y++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
            System.out.println ("\t\t\tName: " + TheStu[y].getfName() + " " + TheStu[y].getsName());
            System.out.println ("\t\t\tAge: " + TheStu[y].getstuAge());
            System.out.println ("\t\t\tTelephone No. 0" + TheStu[y].getphone());
            System.out.println ("\t\t\tEnrolled on the " + TheStu[y].getcourseType() + " Course.");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
        }

    }// end of class
}

class Stu
{
    private String sName;
    private String fName;
    private int stuAge;
    private int phone;
    private String courseType;

    Stu (String s, String f, int a, int p, String c)
    {
        sName = s;
        fName = f;
        stuAge = a;
        phone = p;
        courseType = c;
    }

    String getsName()
    {
        return sName;
    }   

    String getfName()
    {
        return fName;
    }   

    int getstuAge()
    {
        return stuAge; 
    }

    int getphone()
    {
        return phone; 
    }

    String getcourseType()
    {
        return courseType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something pretty basic, you could change your courses into a String array so you could store both courses. Also when asking the user to input a course name, you could have an ALL option, so you automatically register the student for all courses. See below for a slightly modified version of your code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student
{
public static void main(String[] args)//The main method; starting point of the program.
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String surName, foreName, courseName;
    String[] courses = new String[]{};
    int age,telephone;

    System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");    
    System.out.println("\t\t\tWelcome to the Mobile College's Student Records");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
    System.out.println("\nHow many students would you like to add?");
    int noStudents = input.nextInt();

    Stu [] TheStu = new Stu [noStudents];

    for (int x = 0; x < noStudents; x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter Surname: ");
        surName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter Forename: ");
        foreName = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter Age: ");
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter Telephone No. ");
        telephone = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Which courses do you want to add the student to? .......Literacy or Numeracy or both ");

        courseName = input.nextLine();
        // change to either upper case or lower case for easy treatment
        courseName = courseName.toUpperCase();
        // Also verify that the user entered a valid course name
        if(courseName.equals("LITERACY")){
            courses = new String[]{"LITERACY"};
        } else if(courseName.equals("NUMERACY")){
            courses = new String[]{"NUMERACY"};
        } else if(courseName.equals("BOTH")){
            courses = new String[]{"LITERACY", "NUMERACY"};
        } else{
            System.out.println("Error : You entered an invalid option.... \n This student won't be registered for any courses");
        }

        TheStu [x] = new Stu (surName, foreName, age, telephone, courses);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < noStudents; y++)
    {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
        System.out.println ("\t\t\tName: " + TheStu[y].getfName() + " " + TheStu[y].getsName());
        System.out.println ("\t\t\tAge: " + TheStu[y].getstuAge());
        System.out.println ("\t\t\tTelephone No. 0" + TheStu[y].getphone());
        System.out.println ("\t\t\tEnrolled in the following courses : ");
        courses = TheStu[y].getcourseTypes();
        for(int i = 0; i < courses.length; i++){
            System.out.println(courses[i]);
        }
        if(courses.length < 1){
            System.out.println("No Courses");
        }
        System.out.println("\t\t\t***********************************************");
    }

}// end of class
}

class Stu
{
private String sName;
private String fName;
private int stuAge;
private int phone;
private String[] courseTypes;

Stu (String s, String f, int a, int p, String[] c)
{
    sName = s;
    fName = f;
    stuAge = a;
    phone = p;
    courseTypes = c;
}

String getsName()
{
    return sName;
}   

String getfName()
{
    return fName;
}   

int getstuAge()
{
    return stuAge; 
}

int getphone()
{
    return phone; 
}

String[] getcourseTypes()
{
    return courseTypes;
}
}
```

I tried as much as possible not to make any serious changes to your code as i assume you're a beginner, but there are a lot of changes you could make to improve your code. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Your brilliant thaaaannnnk you :) I am a beginner and you have really helped me with something which now looks easy now I have visually seen  the new code :) Happy coding indeed!

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for the course name, keep asking until they have entered in a [sentinal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).  Inside `Stu` keep an `List<String> courseTypes`.  Store the entered courses in courseTypes.  Also, you may want to add a set value to some of the fields in `Stu`.  What if their phone number changes?